# I can't run my test until I pull my code from repository

Tags: git, teamcity, pull

I'm sorry for my English, put I really need help with this problem.
I running my test with Teamcity 8.1.5 and I'm using a remote server repository, put not Github, it's a sever machine, so, my problem is when I give a commit from IDE(PHPStorm), the TeamCity automatiacally should run the build step, but not executed until I do manually pull in my git repository

Answer (score 0):

To make TeamCity run build if change is detected in repository, add a [VCS Build Trigger](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Configuring+VCS+Triggers) to your build configuration

Comment: Thanks for answering, already I had that configuration...but I found the solution set

Comment: I change VCS checkout mode to Automatically o agent